# update.php fails for 1.36.2, how to proceed

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-installation

In Ubuntu 21.10 I am updating mediawiki from 1.31.n to 1.36.2. My wiki uses MySQL and PHP 7.4. I have arrived at the step to run update.php. But the following happens

```
.../maintenance$ php7.4 update.php
MediaWiki 1.36.2 Updater

Your composer.lock file is up to date with current dependencies!
InvalidArgumentException from line 519 of /var/www/html/mediawiki-1.36.2/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php: Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database::getClass no viable database extension found for type 'mysql'
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: Missing php mysql extension? `sudo apt install php-mysql`

Comment: Thanks, perfect. I had not installed php7.4-mysql. Now it works. So solved